# How to set Expected date value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

> Expected Date = Open Date + 48 hours

Here is the query np.date_value is open date value it should be incremented by 48 hours.Can any show me how to increment the time

```
select t1.object_id ,t2.date_value 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t2.id=9137981425113344284
and t1.type_id=9137981352013344075;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can add or subtract whole days from a `date` with the `+` and `-` operators, respectively. So:

```
select no.object_id ,np.date_value + 2 AS expected_date
from nc_objects no
join nc_params np
on no.object_id = np.object_id and np.attr_id=9137981425113344284
and no.object_type_id=9137981352013344075;
```